# Mapping number to colors

Tags: c#, colors

I am currently working on an application in C# (UWP) and *as a side problem* (Not the main problem I am working on) I would need to map some numbers to colors.

Now the restrictions are:
1) The number of possible options is variable. (so it is not "four" colors or something like that but different everytime the program runs)

2) The colors have to be distinguishable enough.

Right now, the results can be in a a RGB byte array. 
Any suggestions on how to do this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing that "distinguishable" means close numbers shall have huge color-difference and each color shall have a minimum "distance" to the others. Is that correct? ( for example : "1" => Red , "2" => completely different color, while "100000" could have a red-ish mapping but still distinguishable from "1"'s mapping )

Comment: The #RRGGBB is just a 3 byte number when you think about it.  Any 3 byte number will do and will produce a unique color.  Please clarify what you mean.  You mean you need colors that work well together?

Comment: "The colors have to be distinguishable enough." I would suggest to read some literature on visual perception. As to the rest [Color.FromRgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb(v=vs.110).aspx) method might help you there

Comment: Take a look at this: http://devmag.org.za/2012/07/29/how-to-choose-colours-procedurally-algorithms/

Comment: See also: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463/how-can-i-find-an-optimum-set-of-colors-for-10-players

Comment: Maybe you could use `HSV` colors, use different values for `H`, and keep `S` and `V` the same.

Answer (score 1):

How about code like this?

```
        List<int> nums = new List<int> { 130049, 652, 832 }; //your numbers to map
        List<byte[]> colors = new List<byte[]>(); //to store byte[] objects
        int squared = 255 * 255;

        foreach (int n in nums)
        {
            var RGBBytes = new byte[3] { 0, 0, 0 }; //RGB values

            decimal quotient = n / squared;
            var mod = n % squared;
            byte theByte = (byte)Math.Floor(quotient);
            RGBBytes[0] = theByte;

            quotient = mod / 255;
            mod = mod % 255;
            theByte = (byte)Math.Floor(quotient);
            RGBBytes[1] = theByte;

            theByte = (byte)Math.Floor((decimal)mod);
            RGBBytes[2] = theByte;

            colors.Add(RGBBytes); //saving RGB values for a color
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", colors.Select(c => string.Join("-", c))));
```